# Printing string to BIOS Video Memory not working

Tags: assembly, operating-system, bootloader, bochs, video-memory

So, im using Bochs to run my bootloader and https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~exr/lectures/opsys/10_11/lectures/os-dev.pdf
Chapter 4.1.

Im trying to print to the BIOS console by writing to the video memory directly but when I run Bochs, I see no printed string. The code is have is actually identical to the code on the PDF. 
Am missing something? Is there a Bochs setting im forgetting or something the PDF didnt tell me?

Here is the assembly file containing the function

```
 ;
; A simple collection of string routines for 32-bit protected mode.
;
[bits 32]
VIDEO_MEMORY equ 0xB8000
WHITE_ON_BLACK equ 0x0f         ; Color mode for the text to be written

PrintString:    ; Assume ebx holds memory address of string.
    ; edx will hold start of video memory
    ; Recall that each character written will take up 2 bytes of video memory
    ; So any particular row or column on the screen will have mem location = 0xb80000
    ; + 2 * (80r + c)

    ; The way this code is written, its always writing starting from the start of the
    ; video memory at 0xb8000, the top left of the screen, replacing everything there.

    pusha
    mov edx, VIDEO_MEMORY

    PrintLoop:
        mov al, [ebx]            ; Only ebx can be used to index
        mov ah, WHITE_ON_BLACK

        cmp al, 0
        je ExitRoutine

        mov [edx], ax

        inc ebx
        add edx, 2

        jmp PrintLoop

    ExitRoutine:
        popa
        ret
```

Here is my actual boot logic.

```
;
; A simple boot sector program that loops forever.
;

[bits 32]
[org 0x7c00]

mov ebx, welcome_msg
call PrintString

jmp $

%include "string_utils.s"

welcome_msg db 'WELCOME TO BASICOS OMFG!', 0
goodbye_msg db 'Goodbye! Thanks for using my BasicOS!', 0

times 510 -( $ - $$ ) db 0

dw 0xaa55
```

Comment: What is the value of `DS`?

Comment: Are you aware that the code is for 32-bit protected/unreal mode? Your bootloader isn't just what's in the second snippet, right?

Comment: Since you are targeting code for 16-bit real mode (your bootloader didn't switch to protected mode) you need to use `bits 16` and not `bits 32` . Because of a quirk in the way BIOSes in 386 machines and most 386 emulators boot they end up in [unreal mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreal_mode). You should be able to use 32-bit registers with 32-bit addresses for data with 16-bit instructions. This of course wouldn't work on an 8086 or 80286 processor (and probably some ancient 80386 hardware)

Comment: My comment doesn't apply to BOCHS though

Comment: Thanks guys, but I figured out the problem. I had not properly switched to protected mode. Everythings fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You're currently in real mode since you're in a bootloader, so you can't write to that as a long mode address.  Instead, set `DS` to 0xb800 and then use `ebx` as an offset:

```
mov ax, 0xb800
mov ds, ax
mov bx, 0
mov [bx], 0x412e  ; A with a green background, yellow foreground
```

Otherwise you're writing to an offset from wherever DS is currently.

Comment: In unreal mode the 32-bit addressing would work with the cached descriptors most BIOSes have set up at boot time. I'd expect his code should work by just replacing `bits 32` with `bits 16` and running on most 80386 hardware (including 386 VMs and emulators). But programming for real mode directly as you are doing will of course work on 8086+ which is a bonus.

Comment: I think he has a bootsector here, though, so unreal mode won't really apply.  I'm basing that on his `ORG` statement and the context of what he's writing in the code.

Comment: Most 386 BIOSes (including virtual ones) boot into unreal mode. Prior to reaching the boot sector they have actually switched into protected mode to do some processing and come back out before the boot sector is run. Many people don't realize this,. Your code won't care which real mode is being used (as I said a bonus).  I was just making the observation that with the OPs code he may find his code working as expected just by using `bits 16`.

Comment: Ah, that's interesting.  I wasn't aware of that.  Thanks.

Comment: I figured out the problem. I had not properly switched to protected mode. Everythings fine now. Literaly took me 15 days to figure it out. No biggie, now I know.